# items horizontally stack where they vertically do not

Tags: html, css

If I change between landscape and portrait then with portrait I get rows like it's supposed to. In landscape, I do get columns but they are all on top of each other. Why is that?

html:

```
<div class="itemContainer">
    <div class="item1"></div>
    <div class="item2"></div>
    <div class="item3"></div>
    <div class="item4"></div>
    <div class="item5"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.itemContainer {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div {
    position: absolute;
}




.item1 {
    background: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    animation: animateIn 1s 0.4s 1 cubic-bezier(0.535, 0.185, 0.890, 0.435) alternate both;
}

.item2 {
    background: rgb(0, 255, 0);
    animation: animateIn 1.2s 0.4s 1 cubic-bezier(0.535, 0.185, 0.890, 0.435) alternate both;
}

.item3 {
    background: rgb(0, 0, 255);
    animation: animateIn 1.4s 0.4s 1 cubic-bezier(0.535, 0.185, 0.890, 0.435) alternate both;
}

.item4 {
    background: rgb(255, 255, 0);
    animation: animateIn 1.6s 0.4s 1 cubic-bezier(0.535, 0.185, 0.890, 0.435) alternate both;
}

.item5 {
    background: rgb(255, 0,255);
    animation: animateIn 1.8s 0.4s 1 cubic-bezier(0.535, 0.185, 0.890, 0.435) alternate both;
}

@keyframes animateIn {
    0% {
        left: 100%;
    }
    100% {
        left: 0;
    }
}



@media only screen and (orientation : landscape) { 

    div {
        width: 20%;  
        height: 100%;      
     }

    .item1 {left: 0%}
    .item2 {left: 20%}
    .item3 {left: 40%}
    .item4 {left: 60%}
    .item5 {left: 80%}


}


@media only screen and (orientation : portrait) { 

    div {
        width: 100%;  
        height: 20%;
     }

    .item1 {top: 0%}
    .item2 {top: 20%}
    .item3 {top: 40%}
    .item4 {top: 60%}
    .item5 {top: 80%}

}
```

jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/clankill3r/yzc8mty8/5/

update: screenies:

portrait good:
[image]

landscape bad:
[image]

Comment: Looks great to me, chromium 41 on debian. Can you post a screenshot of you problem?

Comment: @VictorNitu and Kawinesh, screenshots added!

Comment: maybe your browser has some (bad, in your case) user agent stylesheet applied? Use the element inspector to see anything that shouldn't be there, then nail it via CSS. (i.e. browser is setting a display: block, while you need a display: inline-block)

Answer (score 0):

It is because of your animation just remove it.

```
animation: 1.8s cubic-bezier(0.535, 0.185, 0.89, 0.435) 0.4s alternate both 1 running animateIn;
```

Or change in animation.

It will works great check [Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/yzc8mty8/7/)

Comment: What does my animation remove?

Comment: @clankill3r `animation: none !important;` will remove your animation in landscape.